# Why does my grass looks burned after mowing?

Tags: plant-care, grass

I recently did mowing and my grass looks burned and faded. I saw some post about this but I am not sure if this is moss or leftovers from mowing. I am aiming for green lush grass.

After looking on what height I put it on, I thought the higher the better but it was opposite according to mower manual.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you participate in no-mow May? How much rain have you had lately? What area in the world do you live in?

Comment: @Jurp I did mowed in may what is no-mow may? No we did not have rain recently. I m in north west UK

Comment: What height is your mower set to? That looks way too short from the pictures. 3"/75mm is about as low as you should go unless you're in "specialized athletic turf" (golf greens, lawn bowling) which is quite the royal pain to maintain. Short grass has short roots and expires easily.

Comment: No-Mow May is the concept of not mowing your lawn for a month and then mowing it too short in June (lawn grass should never be cut by more than one-third its height at any one time). No-Mow May originated in the UK in 2019 (I don't practice it in the US because most scientists consider it a terrible idea for us here).

Comment: The grass looks like it was mown too short during a time of reduced soil moisture/drought.

Comment: @Jurp I added more details in question. It seem the height work opposite. I did it on 2cm. Now question is what can I do protect it for burning and growing up again. It is my first time mowing.

Comment: Also new blades tend to need sharpened after about 25 hours of use. The angle can go from 30 to 45 depending on your needs...

Answer (score 2):

From the images, it appears your mower may need its blades sharpening - I can see chewed up ends left behind rather than cleanly cut ones, though that may just be the result of cutting overly long grass with a cylinder mower. The images do suggest you had not cut the grass before May, possibly late into May and maybe not at all this year till May; if that's the case, then a brown, uneven appearance is inevitable if you left it that long, especially if you cut it too short.

Regardless, it will recover over time; do not apply fertilisers or mosskillers while we are in drought. What it needs is water, preferably in the form of good rainfall. Looking at the weather forecast, there does seem to be a possibility of rain within the next few days, and where you live is, in theory, a higher rainfall area of the UK. It's difficult to say if there is any moss present because of the lawn's current appearance - when the weather is damp and it starts growing again, it should be easier to tell then.

In respect of 'No Mow May', I don't know who thought that one up, but I don't think it was a good idea at all. Late April and May are when grass in the UK grows really, really fast; not cutting for the whole of May means you're likely to end up with grass 4 feet high, not something than can easily be cut with an electric mower (and particularly not with a cylinder mower) because it will burn the motor out, you'd need to use a strimmer or scythe first. The most sensible idea is to cut (probably once a week) to leave it high during May (and ongoing if we are in drought) which is what you were attempting in the first place.

Comment: The mower was brand new. It’s flymo rollermo. So not sure why chewed ends. So is good to water them at a offpeak time (when sun is hour or 2) away from sunset as peak hour watering will make water burn the grass? I m looking to take care of grass like u said water will help but does timing water and how much is too much?

Comment: Watering a lawn is an awful waste of precious water, but if you must water it, use a hosepipe with a sprinkler attached and run the sprinkler for half an hour max on each area of grass, preferably late afternoon/early evening. More than that is unnecessary. WE don't usually water home lawns in the UK - we know they will recover once rain arrives.

Comment: Thanks. I remember u recommended lawn book to me last year. I had co fusion if was moss or thraw as both picture look like that. I think I did wrong. I wanted a lush garden to sit during winter and it went opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Having owned a different Flymo in the past, I would suggest that it can not cope with the length of the grass.  So, it hasn't cut it properly, just smashed it.  As mentioned, the grass will recover.

But you may have to find some other method to shorten the grass first.  Because, when it's that tall and sparse, it requires a fast sharp blade to cut it.  And I don't think your Flymo will be that fast.